# In BeautifulSoup, Ignore Children Elements While Getting Parent Element Data

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have html as follows:

```
<html>
    <div class="maindiv">
        text data here 
        <br>
        continued text data
        <br>
        <div class="somename">
            text & data I want to omit
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

I am trying to get only the the text found in the `maindiv`element, without getting text data found in the `somename` element. In most cases, in my experience anyway, most text data is contained within some child element. I have ran into this particular case however where the data seems to be contained somewhat *will-nilly* and is a bit harder to filter.

My approach is as follows:

`textdata= soup.find('div', class_='maindiv').get_text()`

This gets all the text data found within the `maindiv` element, as well as the text data found in the `somename` div element.

The logic I'd like to use is more along the lines of:
`textdata = soup.find('div', class_='maindiv').get_text(recursive=False)` which would omit any text data found within the `somename` element.

I know the `recursive=False` argument works for locating only parent-level elemenets when searching the DOM structure using BeautifulSoup, but can't be used with the `.get_text()` method.

I've realized the approach of finding all the text, then subtracting the string data found in the `somename` element from the string data found in the `maindiv` element, but I'm looking for something a little more efficient.

Comment: What if there are more than one br? or someother div without class as something other than `somename`?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like an approach that could be adapted to handle both situations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not that far from your subtracting method, but one way to do it (at least in Python 3) is to discard all child divs.

```
s = soup.find('div', class_='maindiv')

for child in s.find_all("div"):
    child.decompose()

print(s.get_text())
```

Would print something like:

```
text data here

        continued text data
```

That might be a bit more efficient and flexible than subtracting the strings, though it still needs to go through the children first.

Comment: That's more towards what I was looking for, I wasn't aware of the `.decompose()` method. Looks like I need to do a little more reading! I'll test this approach out a bit and see how it performs

Comment: Yeah, found that from BS documentation of course. There's also some other related functions like `extract` and `replace_with`. [Link](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) if someone is interested.

Answer (score 2):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html ='''
<html>
    <div class="maindiv">
        text data here 
        <br>
        continued text data
        <br>
        <div class="somename">
            text & data I want to omit
        </div>
    </div>
</html>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

soup.find('div', class_="maindiv").next_element
```

out:

```
'\n        text data here \n        '
```